Assertion error when solving "big" systems of equations in SymPy
I have a "big" system of linear equations -2016x2015 in the example below, to be exact, and I want to solve it using SymPy, to get a precise solution.
I tried using the following code:
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

M = sym.Matrix(np.eye(2016))
symbols = sym.symbols('a0:2015')

print(M.shape[1], len(symbols))

print(sym.solve_linear_system(M, symbols))

The first print worked fine, and returned 2016 2015, as expected. However, when the system was supposed to be solved below, it instead threw the following exception:
File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py:2311 in solve_linear_system
    assert system.shape[1] == len(symbols) + 1

AssertionError

I don't understand why this is - after all, the first print showed that the assertion should be true...
Why is this happening?
Thanks in advance!

you should set sym.symbols to 'a0:2016'
symbols = sym.symbols('a0:2015')
print(symbols[-1])
# >>> a2014
print(len(symbols))
# >>> 2015
print(M.shape[0])
# >>> 2016

edit: Disregard the above. In the file solver.py solve linear system is defined as
solve_linear_system(system, *symbols, **flags)

symbols is assumed to be a number of separate parameters. In that case you should run the solver as
solve_linear_system(M, *symbols)


But I'm supposed to get M.shape[1] == len(symbols) + 1, no? The number of rows should be arbitrary

sorry, typo. M.shape[0] == M.shape[1] anyway so that shouldn't be much of a difference

otherwise use numpy.eye(2015, M=2016) np.eye

I tried your solution (setting it to 'a0:2016'), but it yielded the same error...

edit: looked in the file solver.py: solve_linear_system(system, *symbols, **flags) symbols is assumed to be separate parameters, so you should run solve_linear_system(M, *symbols) (i'll put it in the answer too)... side note: eye has no solution, maybe test with np.random.rand(<smaller number>)

I don't recommend using solve_linear_system. You can use linsolve(M) or linsolve(M, *symbols). Note that large nontrivial systems can be extremely slow if exact solutions are sought because of bit growth.
